# How to add an image on top of google map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I want to have an image on my google maps and there will be markers on it. How can I achieve that? I tried to treat the image as a marker using `BitmapDescriptorFactory` but it gives an error. Here is the code :

```
package teamtreehouse.com.iamhere;

public class MapsActivity1 extends FragmentActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity1.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Drawable drawable;

    LatLng photoLatLng = new LatLng(3.811564, 100.815859);
    private float pos = 500f;
    private float trans = 0.5f;

    private ImageView imageView;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap()
    {

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(3.012507, 100.817966)).title("Block A"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(3.611564, 180.815859)).title("Center"));

        mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false); //disable all gesture
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false); //disable zoom button
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true); //enable locate button

        Marker photoMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(photoLatLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.main_map)));
    }


    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
        LatLng latLng2 = new LatLng(3.911564, 101.815859);

        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("You are here!");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng2));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( 16.5f ) ); //zoom
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}
```

and here is the layout file :

```
<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      tools:context=".MapsActivity1"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:background="@drawable/main_map"

/>
```

Comment: Here's a [**marker documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) for android markers, just in case you haven't read through it yet. Otherwise, if you are trying to place something big over google map, you can also try[**overlay**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay). Good luck!!!

Comment: If you want to place an image you can use ground overlays

Comment: Anchor your image to the map using GroundOverlay. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay